# Tomcat websocket client frame

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, websocket, tomcat7

I have the following code that is executed in java as the `clientendpoint` of a websocket

```
   protected void dequeue() throws InterruptedException, IOException
    {
        ByteBuffer bbuf;
        System.out.println("start");
        while((bbuf = messageQueue.take()).get(0) != 0)
        {
            bbuf.position(bbuf.limit());
            if(bbuf.get(0)== 0)
                System.out.println("here");
            bbuf.flip();
            for(Session session : sessionList)
            {
                //Thread.sleep(10000);
                if(!session.isOpen())
                    break;
                session.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(bbuf);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("end");
    }
```

The code works fine when the `Thread.sleep()` that is commented out is put back into the code. However when the `Thread.sleep()` is not included in the code the writes to the websocket sometimes work and other times the `@onClose` is called after the first message is written and the following reason is given,

`CloseReason: code [1002], reason [The client frame set the reserved bits to [7] which was not supported by this endpoint]`

In which the `[7]` will sometimes be a 1,2,etc. I have not been able to find anything really to why this would be happening, does anyone happen to have any insight into what is happening? As of note, I am using `tomcat 7.0.53` to host the ServerSide of the websocket and uses HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the following bug in tomcat, https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57318#c1 updating to `apache tomcat 7.0.57` will fix the issue. Updating to an apache tomcat version greater then `7.0.53` may fix the issue but has not been tested yet.